# Split large integer array into groups of multiples using one performant LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to sort a large integer array into 2 groups, i.e. 1 group the multiples of 4 and the other group the multiples of 5.  How can I do this using just one query?  Keep an eye on the performance which is really important in my case.

To further explain what I need, suppose my list of numbers is `{ 2, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 19,20, 25}` then I would expect my output to be this:

```
new[]
{
    new
    {
        Remainder = 4,
        Numbers = new List<int>(){ 8, 12, 20}
    },
    new
    {
        Remainder = 5,
        Numbers = new List<int>(){10, 20, 25}
    }
}
```

Here's what I have gotten so far:

```
var numberGroupsTimes5 =
    from n in numbers
    group n by n % 5 into g
    where g.Key == 0
    select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };

var numberGroupsTimes4 =
    from n in numbers
    group n by n % 4 into g
    where g.Key == 0
    select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };
```

As you can see it gets me close with 2 queries but as I said I would like a single query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var something = numberGroupsTimes5.Concat(numberGroupsTimes4);
```

to simply concatenate two sequences.

---

It's not entire clear why you use a `GroupBy`, then filter for `Key == 0`. `Remainder` will always be `0`.

Maybe a simple `Where` is enough?
You can simply "combine" your queries by using a logical OR (`||`):

```
var something = numbers.Where(x => x%4 == 0 || x%5 == 0);
```

---

In response to your comment: Are you looking for something like this?

```
var result = new[] {4, 5}
             .Select(d => new 
                    { 
                        Divider = d, 
                        Values = numbers.Where(n => n % d == 0).ToList()
                    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean?

```
var numberGroupsTimes4or5 = from n in numbers
                            group n by n into g
                            where g.Key % 4 == 0 || g.Key % 5 == 0
                            select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
var result = new[] { 4, 5 }
            .SelectMany(x => numbers.Select(n => (n, x)))
            .Where(g => g.n % g.x == 0)
            .GroupBy(g => g.x, (Key, g) => 
                    new { Remainder = Key, Numbers = g.Select(z => z.n) });
```

which gives this result

[image]

Here is a similar approach but this time using a query syntax like in your question.

```
var numbersAndRemainders = new[] { 4, 5 }
            .SelectMany(rem => numbers.Select(n => (n, rem)));

        var numberGroups =
            from n in numbersAndRemainders
            group n by new { remainder = n.n % n.rem, n.rem } into g
            where g.Key.remainder == 0
            select new { Remainder = g.Key.rem, Numbers = g.Select(z => z.n) };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two LINQ methods you could use for this:

```
//This will join the lists, excluding values that already appear once
var result = numberGroupsTimes5.Union(numberGroupsTimes4)

//This will simply append one list the the other
var result = numberGroupsTimes5.Concat(numberGroupsTimes4)
```